# creating dynamic html form

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Trying to learn how to create a dynamic html form. The elements would be defined in the database. Once page is created, the post back data will be handled by controller to insert the data into the database.

I am using playframework 1.2.4

would appreciate any guideline/ helpful links

I can build the page if i know what the elements are and can pull data out for select list from a database table when i call render(param object) from my controller and access the object in my view.

My hack so far:
Created a table with following columns

```
rid
HTMLElementType
ElementName
HTMLElementOptions [if the element type is select]
HTMLDefaultValue [default value for select like 'select a value from below']
HTMLElementEnabled
```

Created a model

```
package models;

import play.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="mytable")
public class DynameForm extends Model{
     public String HTMLElementType;
     public String ElementName;
     public String HTMLElementOptions;
     public String HTMLDefaultValue;
     public String HTMLElementEnabled;
}
```

In my view i loop through checking if it a `<select>` and if so put in an empty option. But not sure if that is right way to go about. In addition in my view i also have to check if it is not  then i have to put in `<input type=>` and build the complete tag

In addition how would I enforce validation on certain fields that are required like example last name/ ssn/ etc? I can alter my table to have a column IsRequired which could help me

Not sure what the right way even is to capture the data on post back

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic, it is difficult to give you any answer on such a problem

Comment: @ Seb Cesbron: Would it help if it were not related to playframework but rather jsp/java?

Comment: Where are these forms being submitted afterwards? I'm not sure how you could deal with submitting of dynamic forms since you don't know what you're going to be storing. With relation to validation, you could define validators using jquery and define the classes as part of your DynameForm.

Comment: @seePatCode: The user data is only validated and if the user is valid is directed to site for now. I figured i would deal with data storage issue down the road. The post is captured in the default controller and is then validated by model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically the problem is to generate an html form. You appear to have figured out your model. What you are missing is a view. I did something like the following once, to generate a model for a simpleDB model.

I provide a list of fields, and UI is generated based on the fields. I only had text fields, and only wanted 2 cases (visible and invisible) fields. Your usecase may require more complexity, so you can adapt as necessary.

`dish.fields` contains the fields with the relevant metadata. Any special things like, requires validation, or isRequired, you will have to provide that information to the view, so it can render the field in appropriate manner.

Simplest way to model it would be to begin with an HTML form, and start generalizing it one field at a time.

```
  #{list items:dish.fields, as:'f'}
    #{field 'f'}
    #{if f.display } 
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"> &{f.name} </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="&{f.name}" name="${dish.getFieldId(f)}" value="${dish.getValue(f)}" ></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    #{/if}
    #{else}
    <input type="hidden" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="&{f.name}" name="${dish.getFieldId(f)}" value="${dish.getValue(f)}" ></input>
    #{/else}
    #{/field}

    #{/list}    
    #{else}
    No fields
    #{/else}
```

I had to define my own fields, but you should be able to get the idea.

You will probably have to have a bunch of different input types for different use cases, so start with simple and generalize as you go on. You can have a look at the CRUD module implementation as well.

my `DisplayAttribute` class (metadata for the fields) looks something like the following. You can use it as a starting point.

```
public class DisplayAttribute {
    public Boolean display = Boolean.TRUE;
    public String type = "";
    public String  name;

    public DisplayAttribute(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.display = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public DisplayAttribute(String name, Boolean display){
        this.name = name;
        this.display = display;
    }
... overridden equals and hash
}
```

**edit**
*How do the fields get rendered?*
Controller passes the meta data(`DisplayAttribute`) to the view, in this case, meta data only contains name of the field and wether it is displayable or not.

**Model**

Here model contains the fields to render, but you could just as easily retrieve these from a database. My model is generic because I realized I kept on doing the same things over and over again for multiple models.

I implement my own interface which gives me `getFields` method. I also maintain two maps, so that given an attribute, I can get its DisplayAttribute, and given a DisplayAttribute I get its name. I call methods of this model from the view when needed.

```
    public class GenericSimpleDBModel implements SimpleDBModel {

        public static AmazonSimpleDB sdb = null;
        private static final String bracketRemovalPattern = "(^.*?\\[|\\]\\s*$)";
        private Map<DisplayAttribute, Set<String>> data = new TreeMap<DisplayAttribute, Set<String>>(new UuidComparator());
        private Map<String, DisplayAttribute> attributeCache = new HashMap<String, DisplayAttribute>();
        protected final String DOMAIN_NAME;

        public GenericSimpleDBModel() {
            initialize(getFields());
            this.DOMAIN_NAME = "dishes";
        }

    protected void initialize(String[] fields) {
        data = new TreeMap<DisplayAttribute, Set<String>>(new UuidComparator());
        attributeCache = new HashMap<String, DisplayAttribute>();
        for (String f : fields) {
//            if (f.equals(getUUIDField()) || f.equals(getIntegrityField())) {
            if (f.endsWith("uuid") || f.endsWith("integrity")) {
                setValue(f, "", Boolean.FALSE);
            } else {
                setValue(f, "", Boolean.TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
   protected void initialize(Set<DisplayAttribute> fields) {
        data = new TreeMap<DisplayAttribute, Set<String>>(new UuidComparator());
        attributeCache = new HashMap<String, DisplayAttribute>();
        for (DisplayAttribute atr : fields) {
            setValue(atr.name, "");
        }
    }
... more methods
}
```

Comment: could you explain how you can render it, without the html form in your views??

Comment: @R.A I have tried to explain a bit more, let me know if I there is still doubt.

Comment: I have tried to explain it a bit more at http://blog.nasir.rasul.ca/2012/10/creating-dynamic-html-form-in-play.html

Comment: First of all I really thanks to you. I have tried to understand your code. But I couldn't. Later I found out and confirmed that your code is groovy and it's for play framework 1. Anyway I am using version 2. I need to do with JAVA or SCALA. If you can help me to work with JAVA or SCALA?? I really appreciate if i can read some tutorial to work with dynamic html form..

Comment: based on the way question is tagged, I responded in 1.2 syntax. If you need it for 2.x, if you understand the concept, you should be able to port the example. I'll see if I can whip up an example in 2.x. I haven't dabbled too much in the new version, so no promises. I will retag the question

Comment: this question is asked by some one else. I dont know if he wanted in 1x or 2x. But i really want to have it in 2x. I will try to port it as well. try as your side too if u can.. Anyway thank you.

Comment: i am using play 1.2.x and would like to know in the post controller(not the controller used to render on a get but after that), how do you read in the values that the user set in the text fields?  I can't put a parameter in my controller function, correct?

Comment: @DeanHiller In my controller I had those fields available as class level variables, so I could use them across different methods (they were final anyways). This is the approach I took. If you inspect you will still get the variables in request object. You just have to retrieve them using the 'id' that are defined in the generated html. Having the field names on hand in advance means, you just query those directly.